# onChange react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a problem, when I put the user : 1 and password 123 appears to me in console empty strings and I do not understand why someone can help me?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  // Setting up Login Activity title.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { UserName: '',Userpassword: ''}

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)

  }


onChange(e) {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  console.log(this.state);
}



<TextInput

          placeholder="Enter User Name"  
       
          onChange={this.onChange}

          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}

        />

 <TextInput

     
          placeholder="Enter Password"

         
           onChange={this.onChange}
       
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          secureTextEntry={true}

        />
```

I add a friend of the console output of my code, user: 1 , password:123´

my Out

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

1. The `onChange` event doesn't have a `name` property to destructure from `event.target`. `name` is undefined and resolves to the third key `""`.
2. React state updates are asynchronous, so you can't console log the updated state in the same render cycle the update is enqueued in. Notice all your console logs are a "cycle" behind the `onChange` event.

## Solution

Restructure your `onChange` callback be a curried function. Attach to the `onChangeText` prop so the text value is passed, and provide a "name" value for the `TextInput` that matches the state it is updating.

```
onChange = name => value => {
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
}

...

<TextInput
  placeholder="Enter User Name"  
  onChangeText={this.onChange('UserName')}
  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
  style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
/>
```

To log the updated state use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state);
}
```